# Quad Breaker Issue

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, gfci, dryer

We have a new Maytag Bravo dryer.  In our breaker box it is on a quad breaker (15 out and 30 in) with the bathroom and living room outlets and outside outlet.  When I turn the dryer on the GFCI in the bathroom trips.  The dryer runs fine. Any suggestions on what the problem is?

Comment: Sounds like your neutrals are a bit messed up. Upload a picture of the breakers, showing all the wires going into them - you may have to (carefully!) remove the front cover to see the wires.

Comment: Upload a picture of the dryer wiring as well.  It's possible the dryer cord is attached to the machine incorrectly, or there is something going on in the dryer receptacle itself.

Comment: I guess I should of worded it differently.  It didn't do it when we first stated using the dryer.  About a week later.  I unplugged the dryer and then plugged it back in and it worked fine for about week and then started doing it again for the last few days.

Comment: How old is the GFCI? In some cases double stuff (or quad in this case) when the dryer kicks on and off there is a bunch of electrical noise droop on on and when it turns off large spikes. The spikes being directly on the same pole even the same contact point can damage the GFCI, it will usually get worse to the point it will not reset or I have found this quite a few times with GFCI’s that are connected to motor circuits (the dryer motor is huge compared to a fan motor but even a fan can cause this). I would replace the GFCI receptacle since it worked without tripping  in the past.

Comment: Dryers need neutral. Where is the dryer obtaining neutral?   Do both dryer hots go ONLY to the middle poles of the breaker?  Does the dryer neutral go ONLY to the panel neutral bar?

Comment: Yeah, can you post photos of the inside of the box with the GFCI in it for that matter?